# How do I select the part below using RegExr

Tags: regex

I have following output:

```
22:48:53.311146 D 0x00001b1c> WL:DUMP[be6f6fa88dd758e] : bla blah
22:48:53.313141 D 0x00001b1c> WL:DUMP[be6f6fa88dd758e] : bla blah
```

I want to just select (Using RegExr):

```
22:48:53.311146 D 0x00001b1c> WL:DUMP[be6f6fa88dd758e] :
```

How do I get this?

Comment: Doesn't `^.+:` work for this? https://regex101.com/r/FNOmjr/1

Comment: Thanks alot. It works. Exactly what I needed